# Font Face not working in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Can anyone tell me why Internet Explorer is not picking up the Font-Face I have specified below:

http://www.droneboylaundry.com/homepage

I have checked it multiple times can't see any issues in the CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BertholdAkzidenzGroteskCondensed';
    src: url('http://www.droneboylaundry.com/fonts/akzidenzgroteskbe-cn.eot');
    src: url('http://www.droneboylaundry.com/fonts/akzidenzgroteskbe-cn.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
    src:  url('http://www.droneboylaundry.com/fonts/akzidenzgroteskbe-cn.woff') format('woff');
    src:  url('http://www.droneboylaundry.com/fonts/akzidenzgroteskbe-cn.ttf') format('truetype');
    src:  url('http://www.droneboylaundry.com/fonts/akzidenzgroteskbe-cn.svg#BertholdAkzidenzGroteskCondensed') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: The page is very complex, with CSS and JS. Try to reduce the problem an essential simpler case that can be analyzed.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 has bugs loading the eot files.

If you add a question mark to the end of the url for all the eot includes, it should work:

```
src: url('http://www.droneboylaundry.com/fonts/akzidenzgroteskbe-cn.eot?');
```

**EDIT**: From Paul Irish's [Bulletproof @font-face Syntax](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BertholdAkzidenzGroteskCond';
  src: url('http://www.droneboylaundry.com/fonts/akzidenzgroteskbe-cn.eot?') format('eot'), 
  url('http://www.droneboylaundry.com/fonts/akzidenzgroteskbe-cn.woff') format('woff'), url('http://www.droneboylaundry.com/fonts/akzidenzgroteskbe-cn.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

**EDIT 2**: [IE has another bug where the font-family name can't be longer than 31 characters](https://twitter.com/FontSquirrel/status/5775846934). I updated the code above to reflect this change.

Comment: Check my edit. It's definitely an IE bug, you might just have to play around to get it to work.

Comment: Change your font-family name - IE has a **second** bug where names can't be longer than 31 characters and yours is 32! Unbelievable

Comment: OMG Ryan I need to send you some serious beer brother, MUCH APPRECIATED!!! Thank You

Comment: How do I give you Rep/ Feedback for this? Just let me know

Comment: Hit the up arrow and the checkmark on the left of my answer to accept it, maybe it will help the next person that has to wrestle with IE lol.