# Font Face not working for Internet Explorer 10.. WHY?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Can anyone tell me why Internet Explorer is not picking up the Font-Face I have specified below:

http://www.droneboylaundry.com/homepage

I have been looking at it for nearly an hour now ... any help is greatly appreciated!

@font-face {

```
font-family: 'BertholdAkzidenzGroteskCondensed';


src: url('http://www.droneboylaundry.com/fonts/akzidenzgroteskbe-cn.eot');


src: url('http://www.droneboylaundry.com/fonts/akzidenzgroteskbe-cn.eot') format('embedded-opentype');

   src:  url('http://www.droneboylaundry.com/fonts/akzidenzgroteskbe-cn.woff') format('woff');


   src:  url('http://www.droneboylaundry.com/fonts/akzidenzgroteskbe-cn.ttf') format('truetype');


   src:  url('http://www.droneboylaundry.com/fonts/akzidenzgroteskbe-cn.svg#BertholdAkzidenzGroteskCondensed') format('svg');
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Font Face not working in Internet Explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480137/font-face-not-working-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Download those font files and host them on your own server (if not doing so already)
2. Use a relative reference to them, like this

`src: url('/fonts/akzidenzgroteskbe-cn.ttf') format('truetype');`